# ContextMenu in macOS App SwiftUI on Button Tap

Tags: macos, swiftui

I want to tap a button and show a context menu in SwiftUI for a macOS app. I can see the button but when I tap the button nothing happens.

```
let menuItems = ContextMenu {
        Button("Today") {}
        Button("Tomorrow") {}
    }

 Button {
                    // action
                } label: {
                    Label("Add Date", systemImage: "calendar")
                        .contextMenu(menuItems)
                }
```

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you just look for menu with button style, like

[image: demo]

```
 Menu {
      Button("Today") {}
      Button("Tomorrow") {}
 } label: {
      Label("Add Date", systemImage: "calendar")
 }
 .menuStyle(.borderedButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing a `Button` around the context menu means that the button is managing  all the click events, and none of them get through to the `contextMenu` modifier.

You could move the modifier to attach onto the button itself, and you get something that executes the button action on left click, but displays the context menu when right-clicked:

```swift
  Button {
    print("Clicked")
  } label: {
    Label("Add Date", systemImage: "calendar")
  }
  .contextMenu(menuItems)
```

[image: Context menu displayed on button]

Comment: Thanks! This work but how can I make it work on Button tap. Your code works when I right click on the Button.

Comment: I've not had a need to context menus on left click in macOS so I don't 100% know, I'm afraid! The closest I can find in the docs is to use `Menu` instead, which produces a drop-down style menu. By default it expands horizontally to fill the whole space, but you could use a `frame` modifier if needed.